# Firefox PHP Include and CSS

Tags: php, html, css, include

My problem is a bit of a specific one I feel, basically I'm having trouble with some CSS styles showing in Firefox when using a PHP include.

I have my index.php and header.php, which is included in the index file. The header file contains code from this tutorial http://www.basewebmaster.com/css/simple-css-drop-down-menu.php, which works fine when I run it in a standalone html file in Firefox, but in the header.php file it doesn't show correctly where it does in every other browser.

The site is here: http://createful.com/cleave

If you view it in any browser other than FF it should show a nice drop down menu, but in FF it really messes up, only in my instance of using an include statement for the header.php file (a static html file works perfectly).

My index.php file has this code:

```
<?php include("header.php"); ?>
```

And my header.php has the exact code from the tutorial I linked earlier in this post. My style.css also has the exact code as in the tutorial.

For comparison, here's a static version of the same code, which works perfectly in FF: http://www.createful.com/cleave/test/index.html

I'm not too sure what other information is needed to solve this, but hopefully this will be sufficient, I can provide any other information if needed though.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT - Here's the complete code for index.php and header.php

Index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Jon Cleave</title>

    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="js/scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jScrollPane.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/jScrollPane.css" />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.open1').hide();

            $('.close1').click(function() {
                $('.info').slideUp('slow', function() {
                    // Animation complete.
                });

            $('.close1').hide();
            $('.open1').show();

            });
        });

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.open1').click(function() {
                $('.info').slideDown('slow', function() {
                    // Animation complete.
                });

            $('.open1').hide();
            $('.close1').show();

            });
        });
    </script>

</head>    
<body>

<?php require "header.php"; ?>

<!-- BEGIN BACKGROUND PICTURES -->
<div id="loader" class="loading"></div>
<div id="bkgallery">

    <ul>
        <li><img src="work/work1.png" id="im1" alt=""/> </li>  
        <li><img src="work/triworks_arch2.jpg" id="im2" alt=""/> </li> 
        <li><img src="work/triworks_arch3.jpg" id="im3" alt=""/> </li>  
    </ul>

    <div class="close1">x</div>
    <div class="open1">+</div>
    <div class="info">Info box 1</div>
    <div class="info two">Info box 2</div>

    <a href="" class="next" title="next page">next</a>
    <a href="" class="prev" title="prev page">prev</a>
</div><!-- #bkgallery -->
<!-- END BACKGROUND PICTURES -->

<!-- END CONTENT -->

<!-- END FOOTER -->

</body>
```

Footer.php

```
    <div id="header">
    <div id="logo"><h1>Jon Cleave</h1></div>

    <div id="nav">
        <ul class='drop-down'>
        <li class="top"><a href='#nogo'>index</a>
            <ul>
            <li><a href='#nogo1'>Male</a></li>
            <li><a href='#nogo2'>Female</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="top"><a href='#nogo3'>case studies</a>
            <ul>
            <li><a href='#nogo4'>Blond</a></li>
            <li><a href='#nogo5'>Brown</a></li>
            <li><a href='#nogo6'>Black</a></li>
            <li><a href='#nogo7'>Red</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="top"><a href='#nogo8'>cv</a>
            <ul>
            <li><a href='#nogo9'>Blue</a></li>
            <li><a href='#nogo10'>Green</a></li>
            <li><a href='#nogo11'>Brown</a></li>
            <li><a href='#nogo12'>Grey</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="top"><a href='#nogo8'>contact</a>
            <ul>
            <li><a href='#nogo9'>Email</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div><!-- header -->
```

Comment: That should be `include "header.php";` the parenthesis are not required.

Comment: And in another browsers?

Comment: It works perfectly in every other browser, just FF, and only when I do it with a PHP include.

Comment: For comparison, here's a static version of the same code, which works in FF: http://www.createful.com/cleave/test/index.html

Comment: instead of `include` try `require`.

Comment: @dalehumphries Is everything ok with your FF? I've tested it and works like a charm.

Comment: It's broken in my FF (v 12.0, Windows 7). No extensions except Firebug.

Comment: @vascowhite That really doesn't matter. Either works.

Comment: @PLB, I assume my FF is fine. I'm on OSX and FF is v12.0. It seems to vary from machine to machine.

Comment: Can you post your entire `index.php` and `header.php` code?

Comment: It's something concerned with how your browser parses page. take a look in documentation.

Comment: @ChrisFletcher Okay, added to the original question

Comment: @PLB Where would I look to find that? I have no knowledge of how browsers parse pages or how to fix issues related to that.

Comment: @PLB my firefox seems to have an error too, but no error logs...

Comment: Love the beating around the bush here. First suggest removing optional parentheses, then switching the require, neither of which has any effect, then throw the question asker a task that most people have no clue how to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem originates in your stylesheet, lines 284 and 299:

```
.close1 {
    position: fixed;
    color: #fff;
    top: 65px;
    left: 30px;
    display: block;
    background: #444;
    width: 208px;
    padding: 0px 0px 1px 8px;
    opacity:0.8;
    z-index: 0;
    background-image: url("../img/close.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
}

.open1 {
    position: fixed;
    color: #fff;
    top: 65px;
    left: 30px;
    display: block;
    background: #444;
    width: 208px;
    padding: 0px 0px 1px 8px;
    opacity:0.8;
    z-index: 0;
    background-image: url("../img/close.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

Notice the opening `"` and the missing closing `"` for the `background-image`? That causes all declarations after that to be ignored.

Comment: That's it! I can't believe I didn't notice those errors. Thank you so, so much.

Answer (score 2):

Usually when this happens the problem is because your files are encoded in UTF-8 with BOM. The BOM acts as an invisible character but causes layout problems.

Most editors (beyond Notepad) allow you to encode as "UTF-8 without BOM", so you should use that option if you can.

If not, don't use UTF-8. Personally I'm still doing all my stuff in ISO-8859-1, and if I ever need a Unicode character I use an HTML entity.

Explanation of BOM - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_Order_Mark

Comment: Can you elaborate on what BOM is please?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_Order_Mark - explains it far better than I ever could.

Comment: Thank you for the response. So I either use a text editor that can encode as UTF-8 without BOM, or change my charset from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1? And this should fix this problem?